# Preselect next Monday with jQuery Datepicker

Tags: jquery, datepicker

How would I do to always make the next Monday (or any other day that is coming up) preselected with jQuery Datepicker?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can call the setDate() like

```
$('#myselector').datepicker({ 
    /*options*/
}).datepicker('setDate', '+' + (8 - new Date().getDay()))
```

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/5xf2dp4h/)

Answer (score 0):

From: [jQuery datepicker api](http://api.jqueryui.com/datepicker/#option-defaultDate)

```
var d = new Date();
var daysToMonday = 8-d.getUTCDay();

$( ".selector" ).datepicker({
    defaultDate: +daysToMonday
});
```